# Optimize multiple group_concat

Tags: join, mariadb, mysql-5.6, subquery, group-concatenation

Just wondering if this query could be optimized or if sub-queries would be better?

```
select t.entry_id, 
t.title, 
d.field_id_249 as unique_id, 
d.field_id_577 as keywords,
d.field_id_681 AS video,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sub.parent_id = 0 THEN sub.cat_name ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR ",") as subject_name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sub.parent_id = 0 THEN sub.cat_url_title ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR ",") as subject_url, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sub.parent_id = 0 THEN sub.cat_order ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR ",") as subject_order,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sub.parent_id != 0 THEN sub.cat_name ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR ",") as topic_name, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sub.parent_id != 0 THEN sub.cat_url_title ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR ",") as topic_url, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sub.parent_id != 0 THEN sub.cat_order ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR ",") as topic_order,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sw2.status = "open" THEN sw2.title ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR ",") as software_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sw2.status = "open" THEN sw2.url_title ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR ",") as software_url,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN sw2.status = "open" THEN sw3.field_id_166 ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR ",") as software_icon,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT grade.cat_description SEPARATOR ",") as grades, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ab.grade_code != "" THEN ab.grade_code ELSE NULL END SEPARATOR ",") as ab_grade, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ab.state SEPARATOR ",") as ab_state, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ab.state_id SEPARATOR ",") as ab_standards
from exp_channel_titles AS t
inner join exp_playa_relationships as p on (t.entry_id = p.child_entry_id)
left join exp_channel_data as d on (t.entry_id = d.entry_id)
left join api_ab AS ab on (ab.unique_id = d.field_id_249)
left join exp_category_posts AS cp on (cp.entry_id = p.parent_entry_id)
left join exp_categories AS sub on (sub.cat_id = cp.cat_id)
left join exp_playa_relationships AS sw1 on (sw1.parent_entry_id = t.entry_id)
left join exp_channel_titles AS sw2 on (sw2.entry_id = sw1.child_entry_id)
left join exp_channel_data AS sw3 on (sw2.entry_id = sw3.entry_id)
left join exp_category_posts AS gr on (t.entry_id = gr.entry_id)
left join exp_categories AS grade on (grade.cat_id = gr.cat_id)
where `p`.`parent_field_id` = 678 AND `t`.`status` = 'open' AND FIND_IN_SET("animal", d.field_id_577) OR `t`.`title` LIKE '%animal%'
group by p.child_entry_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You are generating logically unreasonable cartesian product and then technically "fixing" it with DISTINCT (If you survive the generated set volume).
Yes, sub-queries is definitly the way to go here.

Comment: Got it!  Makes sense - but could you give an example of a sub-query that still returns values as group_concat distinct?

Comment: No problem, but tomorrow